# Regex Go mismatch

Tags: regex, go

I have developed some regex in regexr where it works as expected, but when I use it in Go it seems to be mismatching strings.

```
(\+|-)?(((\d{1,3}[, ])(\d{3}[ ,])*\d{3})|\d+)( ?[\.,] ?(\d{3}[, ])*\d+)?
```

For example in regexr the following input does not match:

```
1.12,4.64
```

But in Go it does match.

Comment: Are you aware, that there are many flavours of regular expressions, and something that works for one engine might not work for another?

Comment: Yes I did read the manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(\+|-)?(((\d{1,3}[, ])(\d{3}[ ,])*\d{3})|\d+)( ?[\.,] ?(\d{3}[, ])*\d+)?$
```

Try with anchors.`^$` will disable partial matching.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/4

Comment: Thanks that seems to have done the job. http://play.golang.org/p/JX9Vvcdjtg